# Django. Problems with User model

Tags: django

I got problem when updated project from django 1.6 to django 1.8

I have model Profile

```
class Profile(AbstractUser):
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Middle name"))
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Phone"))
    status = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Status"))
    education = models.CharField(max_length=350, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Education"))
    progress_display = models.BooleanField(default=True, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Display progress"))
    about = models.TextField(blank=True, verbose_name=_("description about"))
    city = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, verbose_name=_("City"))
    current_city = models.CharField(max_length=75, blank=True, verbose_name=_("Current city"))
    birth = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("Birthday"))
    registered = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, help_text=_('Registration date'),
                                      verbose_name=_("registration date"))
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name=_("is_teacher"))
    hide_fields = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    subscription = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True, verbose_name='Подписка на рассылку')
    main_photo = models.ForeignKey('avatar.Photo', blank=True, verbose_name=_("user main-photo"), related_name='avatar', default=None, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('User')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Users')
        ordering = ('-registered', 'id')
        get_latest_by = 'registered'
```

My applications are located in separated folder ("applications"). path to folder i define in settings like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'applications'))
```

I also define my custom User-model in settings (located in Profile application)

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'profile.Profile'
```

it's my install apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'social',
    'photo',
    'profile',
    'qa',
    'main',
    'learn',
    'donate',
    'notifications',
    'articles',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'grappelli',
    'django_extensions',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'rest_framework',
    'djkombu',
    'autofixture',
    'crispy_forms'    
)
```

commands "runserser", 'makemigrations' or 'migrate' work good but createsuperuser return this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/pycharm-3.0.2/helpers/pycharm/django_manage.py", line 23, in <module>
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 176, in run_module
    fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 82, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/home/camaro/programming/imedrese/master/manage.py", line 14, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/camaro/programming/imedrese/master/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/camaro/programming/imedrese/master/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/camaro/programming/imedrese/master/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 190, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/home/camaro/programming/imedrese/master/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 41, in load_command_class
    return module.Command()
  File "/home/camaro/programming/imedrese/master/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "/home/camaro/programming/imedrese/master/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 155, in get_user_model
    "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'profile.Profile' that has not been installed
```

Answer (score 0):

My reputation is insufficient to comment on your question, so I put this here as answer, even if it doesn't answer your question.

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) on extending the `User`-model, your approach seems - sorry - wrong. As far as I can see from your code, you're not doing anything special with your `Profile`, except from adding more information to an account. This can be done using a `OneToOne`-relation with the original Django User (as described in the linked documentation).

That said: I can't see why your model should stop working when upgrading to 1.8. Have you checked the [1.7 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.7/) or [1.8 release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.8/), if they have changed anything regarding custom User-models?

Comment: its not wrong, but its one of aproaches. my problem was with files structure in project =)