# Migrating from auth_user in Django

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I created a custom user model in Django and it worked up fine. However, I decided to create a custom model to suit my needs after the project was up and running.

As a result, I will need to migrate the schema (Currently, when I register a user, the code is still referencing to the the `auth_user` database tables where as the new custom user table is `user`.)

I have set the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in `settings.py` to `userapp.User`, where `userapp` is my custom user app and `User` is the Model that inherits from the `AbstractUser` model.

I am fairly new to Django and cannot understand how to achieve this. One obvious way to clean install the database, which is not something that I'm looking to do as it will remove all my data.

How do I migrate then? I've heard `South` is used for that but I don't know how to use it. Besides I think `South` isn't required in the recent versions of Django.

My version of Django is `1.8.2`.

Comment: Not answering your question, but see [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100063/django-problems-with-user-model/31100276#31100276). Extending the `User` may be an option instead of replacing the model. Could possibly save you some headaches.

Comment: Hi @Mischback, that is what i am doing basically - just adding some fields to my user model. And yes, Django's official docs suggest implementing a `One to One Relationship` with the User model. Could you tell me how to do that (or provide an example link) and how do I use that to save new users data + in forms.

Comment: Never have done it myself, but I would create a completely independent app with a `Profile` model. Just write an ordinary app, with forms, urls, etc. Simply tie it to the existing/used user model by adding a `OneToOne`-field to your model, referencing `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` and do not allow this field to be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently - we used a [data migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to move between the two models. Rough steps:

1. Create the new user model (without telling Django about it), make/apply migrations to create the database table(s)
2. Write a the data-migration to *copy* the data over to the new user model. Then run this migration and update Django to use the new model
3. Now you should be switched over, and can delete/archive the old `auth_user` table as needed

Comment: I did roughly the same thing - created a new user model, added it to `AUTH_USER_MODEL` and used `./manage.py makemigrations` followed by `./manage.py migrate`. When I try to register new users, it says foreign key constraint violation - key not found in `auth_user` even though I am no longer using that table.

Comment: @GauravWadhwani what's foreign key it's looking for? And are you registering new users via the web or CLI interface?

Comment: Hi @Fizzadar .. Registering new users via Web interface. I am getting `Integrity Error: insert or update on table "customer_email" violates foreign key constraint "customer_email_user_id_8eeb3a31aa9371c_fk_auth_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(17) is not present in table "auth_user".`

Comment: Hey @GauravWadhwani, did you find how to solve.. 4 yrs after.. I am getting ta same problem...